# Can't connect to wifi network using QT

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, wifi, qtnetwork

I'm trying to connect to wifi network using the following code
but it is not working also not giving any error

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QNetworkConfiguration cfg;
    QNetworkConfigurationManager ncm;
    auto nc = ncm.allConfigurations();

    for (auto &x : nc)
    {
        if (x.bearerType() == QNetworkConfiguration::BearerWLAN)
        {
            if (x.name() == "Desired Network")
                qDebug() <<"Connecting to "<< x.name();
                cfg = x;
        }
    }
    auto session = new QNetworkSession(cfg);
    session->open();
    return a.exec();
}
```

It is showing the output in the terminal with "desired network's name".

Connecting to Desired Network

Comment: what you actually expect to happen? Note that `QNetworkSession::open();` is asynchronous , is not finished by time you called exec(), and on some systems  does nothing

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have added `QThread::msleep(20000);` after `session->open()` which is giving it 20 seconds to connect but it is still not connecting, also the wifi network is password protected do I have to make any change in code for that?

Comment: From the documentation for [`QThread::msleep`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#msleep): `"Avoid using this function if you need to wait for a given condition to change. Instead, connect a slot to the signal that indicates the change or use an event handler"`.  So connect and react to the relevant [`QNetworkSession` signals](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworksession.html#signals).

Answer (score 1):

Actual NI names in your OS may be different from ones you expect. Try  debug it more verbosely:

```
for (auto &x : nc)
{
    if (x.bearerType() == QNetworkConfiguration::BearerWLAN)
    {
        qDebug() << x.name() << " is a WIFI";
        if (x.name() == "Desired Network")
            qDebug() <<"Connecting to "<< x.name();
            cfg = x;
    }
    else
        qDebug() << x.name() << "\n";
}
```

E.g. on Windows those names would be enclosed in quotes, most likely because of WMIC backend used by Qt to obtain them. If your NI is called "Desired Network" in GUI, it is actually `"\"Desired Network\""`

Comment: Thanks for your response, this part of the code is working just fine(I have updated the question for more clarification). This problem is that it is detecting the network but not connecting to the network.